# Upgrading sudo version for QID-241082, RHSA-2023:0291 vulnerabilty on a Linux server

Tags: sudo, redhat-satellite

If we have a subscription to Red Hat Satellite, can we execute the command `yum update sudo` or do we need to follow the `./configure`, `make` and `make install` sequence of commands?

Answer (score 0):

If your subscriptions are set up correctly,

```
yum update sudo
```

will update the package to a version including the CVE-2023-22809 fix. See [RHSA-2023:0291](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2023:0291.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks, may I know in which scenario do I need to follow ./configure , sudo make && sudo make install commands, please.

Comment: With a supported distribution, never, at least for software provided by the distribution. On RHEL, wait for the relevant errata, and follow the instructions given there.

Comment: thank you, I have tried to check whether my sudo version is vulnerable to this flaw with sudoedit -s / command and i got usage: sudoedit [-Ak ...., as output. I believe in this case I don't need to upgrade the sudo package, correct?

Comment: That doesn’t test this particular CVE, as far as I’m aware. However 22809 is only significant if your `sudo` configuration grants limited `sudoedit` access; if your `sudo` users have general `sudo` access it doesn’t introduce a security risk.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen -very much appreciated!